# prevent click happen in a children element

Tags: jquery

I set a event to a `wrapper div`, but inside this `div`, i have some `buttons`, how can i **prevent** this `wrapper` event happen in the `buttons` ?

**html**:

```
<div class="wrapper-alert"> <!-- click here will pop-up -->
   <div class="somethingElse"> <!-- click here will pop-up -->
      Some text            
   </div>
   <div class="this-is-my-action">
      <button class="inside-alert">Inside</button> <!-- click here will NOT pop-up-->
   </div>
   <div class="somethingElseTo"> <!-- click here will pop-up -->
      Some text            
   </div>
</div>​
```

i made a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NxnW2/37/) to be more clear.

so, basicly, if i click in the `wrapper-alert` some message will pop-up, but if i click in the `button` other thing will happen, **the problem is that the buttons are children from wrapper, so 2 events will fire at once.**

i have try something with `if (e.target !== this) return;` but works only with one `children`, or some basic structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation` method.

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$(".inside-alert").on("click", function(event){
     event.stopPropagation()
     alert('this is my BUTTON' + event.target); // dont pop-up anything
});
```